# Is it possible to unlock windows when A device (phone) is detected?

Tags: android, windows-8

I'm not particularly looking for high levels of security as it's a personal PC, but I've modded my case a bit and it now has a key switch (instead of a power button) which, as it is a key means, I can disable my log in screen on boot and people still can't access my PC (without hotwiring it).

I was just wondering if it's possible to unlock your PC automatically (send keystrokes or something) when a device - probably my phone - is plugged in. It doesn't have to be MY phone specifically, but it'd be even cooler if it was.
It would be even better if when the PC booted up it only logged in automatically IF this phone was plugged in, otherwise it would show the log in screen (and log in automatically from here when the phone gets plugged in).

Essentially my phone would replace the log in screen completely, but you're still given the choice to type a password if you like (or lose the phone).

I'm running Windows 8 and own an HTC One running Android 4.3.
If this isn't possible on Windows, I've been thinking of installing Linux for a while (I assume this is a lot easier on Linux). I just want to know what the best approach to this would be or if it's even possible. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something similar can be done with this tool http://www.rohos.com/support/knowledge-base/access-your-windows-vista-computer-by-using-a-hardware-usb-security-token/

Comment: That's pretty cool, do you reckon it can be used with an MTP device like my phone? (god knows why they switched from mass storage to MTP..)

Comment: Maybe not. but try googling about it nad if you are good with pogramming in windows,u can create a custom login interface that can check the hardware ids of the devices and allow logins

Comment: I'll have a look into it. What language would you recommend for this kind of thing? or is it typical Windows and it needs C# or something. I'm only really experienced in Python and Web languages. Although I do have some Java knowledge too (Perhaps enough if I spent a lot of time on it).

Comment: I recommend C#.Net but,it is also possible with Java